# Poor performance using SQL with Dash

Tags: python, sql, plotly-dash

I have a Dash application to create a dashboard with graph, and all the data of the graphs come from and SQL Server database.
the issue I face is each of the call to the database takes too much time. Here what the stuff I have done to test the difference performance :

My function look like that (I have simplify a lot the inputs)

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id=component_id, component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='adm_level_radio', component_property='value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def myfunction(param):
    # do some computation
    myquery = "SELECT Id, Data FROM MyTable"
    df = sqlmanager.read(myquery)
    # do some computation
```

the computation time is pretty instant, and in the sql part, it takes 20 secondes.
I have try then to run only the SQL part in a normal python file (without Dash) to be sure it is nor related to a non optimize query : it runs in 2 secondes.
I have also try to run a local Flask server that just execute the query and return the data, and replace the SQL part in Dash by a request to the Flask Server, again, the query is executed in 2 seconds.

So is there anything I need to know about SQL and Dash application ? Any good practice that maybe I didn't follow?

I know the issue is not very well explain, but I don't see what can I put more instead of all the Dash Application.
If you need something (configuration of the Dash App) to help me, don't hesitate to put in comment I will edit the post to add all relevant information, but for now I just ask for global idea where the time can be lose in this dash app (it is the first time I develop using Dash so I probably miss something important)

Thanks